# Different control on the same group of accordion in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have 2 angular-js accordions, where one is disabled when the other one is active.
Because of this, they both work when i click one accordion.
Please check on this to see demo : `http://plnkr.co/edit/DMzLtN217F7g75LkbUMh?p=preview`.
What can I do to control them separately?

This is HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
    <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
      <accordion-group is-open="status.open">
      <accordion-heading>
          I can have markup, too! <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.open}"></i>
      </accordion-heading>
          This is just some content to illustrate fancy headings.
    </accordion-group>
    <accordion-group heading="Custom template" template-url="group-template.html">
  Hello
     </accordion-group>
    <accordion-group is-open="status.open">
       <accordion-heading>
           Delete <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.open}"></i>
       </accordion-heading>
       <p>Please, to delete your account, click the button below</p>
       <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
    </accordion-group>
  </accordion>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using angular-ui-bootstrap and you didn't add *ui-bootstrap.min.js* dependency.

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
```

Check this: http://plnkr.co/edit/mPBXZHSFX0dm0KLC1gPC?p=preview

Comment: I have input all required file in it.